# Safari refuses to change the width of the image container to fit the image's width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

I was making my first image gallery with basic css. Everything seemed fine before I checked Safari.
The width of the image container's behaved very strangely.
The width of `image-container` didn't change to fit the width of the image.
[This is how it looks on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xBW.jpg)
[And this is how it looks on any other browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFQWf.jpg)
I added red border to `image-container` to make the problem more noticeable

```
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image5.jpg" alt="Image 5">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image6.jpg" alt="Image 6">
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image7.jpg" alt="Image 7">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 15vw;
  width: auto;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please share reproducible test case / JSFiddle, so we can test the behavior.